# Group theory, the squares of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have a group $G$ with a subgroup $G_2$, which is defined by $G_2:=\{g^2|g \in G \}$.

I have to prove that

i) $G_2\triangleleft G$

ii) all elements of $G/G_2$ have order $\leq2$

iii)if $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism s.t. all $x\in img(\phi)$ have order $\leq2$ then $G_2 \subseteq \ker(\phi)$

The only thing I can think of to start this proof is by finding a homomorphism, for which $\ker(\phi)=G_2$

Comment: Hint for i): If $g' = g^2 \in G_{2}$, then $hg'h^{-1} = hg^2h^{-1} = hgh^{-1}hgh^{-1} = (hgh^{-1})^{2}$. For ii), think of the definition of order in a quotient group: since $(gG_{2})^{2} = g^{2}G_{2}$, then we conclude...

Comment: thank you for the help on i. But I don't understand why $(gG_2)^2=g^2G_2$ should be always true. Because $gG_2gG_2$ isn't always equal to $ggG_2G_2$. I understand that $G_2G_2=G_2$

Comment: you already proved it is normal. When $N$ is normal $gNhN=ghN$

Comment: @RubenMeijs Rightly so, but since $G_2$ is normal, the product of cosets given by $(aG_2,bG_2)\mapsto abG_2$ is well defined.

Comment: Ow of course, multiplication with quotient groups is defined as (gN)(hN)=ghN. And $g^2\in G_2$ so $(gG_2)^2=g^2G_2=G_2$ thus all elements have order $\leq 2$

Comment: The "group" you defined isn't a group at all **if** $\;G\;$ isn't abelian. I guess you meant the subgroup generated by the squares of element in the group: $$G_2=\;langle\;x^2\;:\;x\in G\;\rangle$$

Comment: @Timbuc My interpretation was that it was an assumption of the question that it is a subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt That assumption is wrong, in my opinion, unless it is specified the group $\;G\;$ is abelian or unless it is given that it is the group generated by the squares of elements. I think things like this can create big confusion among students.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes I agree that it is very badly worded. I think the intention was something like: Let $G$ be a group in which the set $G_2 := \{g^2 \mid g \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) Take $h^2 \in G_2$ and $ g \in G $, then $$g^{-1}h^2 g = (g^{-1}hg) (g^{-1}hg) \in G_2$$ This means that $ G_2 \triangleleft G$

ii) Take $\overline{g} \in G/G_2 $, thus $$\overline{g}^2 = \overline{g^2} = 1_{G/G_2} $$ i.e all elements in $G/G_2$ have order $ \leq 2$.

iii) Take $h^2 \in G_2 $, thus $\phi(h^2) \in \text{img}(\phi) $ but $$ \phi(h^2)=\phi(h)^2 = 1 $$ by the hypotheses, and so $G_2 \subseteq \ker(\phi) $

Comment: For clarification, with the last question you use that $\phi (xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ right?

Comment: @RubenMeijs: yes

Answer (score 1):

(i) Let $g' \in G_2.$ Then $g' = g^2$ for some $g \in G.$ Now for every $h \in G$, $hg'h^{-1} = (hgh^{-1})^2 \in G_2.$

(ii) Let $gG \in G/G_2.$ Then $(gG)^2 = g^2G.$

(iii) Let $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ has the above stated property. Then for each $x \in G, \phi(x)^2 = e_H.$ So in particular, for $x \in G_2, \phi(x) = e_H.$ Hence, $G_2 \subseteq $ Ker$\phi.$